# POST Request Not Sending Parameters with Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I followed along with a tutorial on how to use Volley to make HTTP requests (http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-volley-example/) and everything went well there. I am now trying to make a POST request but am having the problem were my POST data isn't being sent to the server.

CustomJSONObjectRequest.java

```
package com.co.pa.ny;

        import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
        import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
        import com.android.volley.Request;
        import com.android.volley.Response;
        import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
        import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;

public class CustomJSONObjectRequest extends JsonObjectRequest {

    public CustomJSONObjectRequest(int method,
                                   String url,
                                   JSONObject jsonRequest,
                                   Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                                   Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {
        // here you can write a custom retry policy
        return super.getRetryPolicy();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });
}
...
public void attemptLogin() {
    String url = "http://example.com";


    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("email", emailField.getText().toString());
    params.put("password", passwordField.getText().toString());

    final CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonRequest = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                                                                            url,
                                                                            new JSONObject(params),
                                                                            this,
                                                                            this);
    jsonRequest.setTag(REQUEST_TAG);

    mQueue.add(jsonRequest);
}
```

On the server I am doing a very simple write to file with:

```
<?php
$file = 'newfile.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= print_r($_POST, TRUE)."\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

When tapping my button in the app my text file is appended with a simple:

```
Array
(
)
```

A tell tale sign that the POST variables aren't being sent. I am able to verify that does work by creating a simple form that POSTs to the URL from the browser. Anyone have any ideas what I am missing to make my POST request work properly from within the app?

Comment: I think it should be `$_POST["REQUEST_TAG"]` (replacing REQUEST_TAG with the tag you send before adding the jsonRequest).

Comment: @TheAnonymous010 Leaving it S just $_POST makes it spit out everything coming through as a POST so that should be picked up anyway.

Comment: That's true, but it may be worth a try just in case there was an error somewhere. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: @TheAnonymous010 I'm away from my code for the night, so I'll give it a shot tomorrow morning. Thanks for throwing out your thoughts.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if it helps or not. I have a couple more ideas if you are just trying to send a string to your website. (Ex. username and password).

Comment: @TheAnonymous010 No dice on adding the request tag to my PHP.

Comment: When I get home later, I'll add some code that I think will help you. I'll bring home in about 4-5 hours.